# Maximize $\langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle$ subject to $\| \mathrm X \|_F = 1$

Tags: matrices, optimization, alternative-proof, qclp

> Given $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$,
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm X \|_F = 1\end{array}$$

I can think of *two* approaches, which I write below. I am interested in *other* approaches.

---

## #1

$$\langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle = \langle \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A) , \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \rangle \leq \|\mbox{vec} (\mathrm A)\|_2 \|\mbox{vec} (\mathrm X)\|_2 = \|\mathrm A\|_F \underbrace{\|\mathrm X\|_F}_{=1} = \|\mathrm A\|_F$$

Hence, the maximizer is $\mathrm X_{\max} := \gamma \mathrm A$, where $\gamma > 0$. From the constraint,

$$1 = \|\mathrm X_{\max}\|_F = \gamma \|\mathrm A\|_F$$

Thus,

$$\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\|\mathrm A\|_F}$$

and

$$\mathrm X_{\max} = \frac{\mathrm A \,\,\,}{\|\mathrm A\|_F}$$

---

## #2

We define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} (\mathrm X, \lambda) := \langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle - \frac{\lambda}{2} (\| \mathrm X \|_F^2 - 1)$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain

$$\mathrm A - \lambda \mathrm X = \mathrm O \qquad \qquad \qquad \| \mathrm X \|_F^2 = 1$$

Hence,

$$\mathrm X = \frac{1}{\lambda} \mathrm A$$

and

$$1 = \| \mathrm X \|_F^2 = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X^T \mathrm X) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \mbox{tr} (\mathrm A^T \mathrm A) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \| \mathrm A \|_F^2$$

and, thus,

$$\lambda^2 = \| \mathrm A \|_F^2$$

or,

$$\lambda = \pm \| \mathrm A \|_F$$

Thus, the minimizer and maximizer are

$$\mathrm X_{\min} := -\frac{\mathrm A \,\,\,}{\| \mathrm A \|_F} \qquad \qquad \qquad \mathrm X_{\max} := \frac{\mathrm A \,\,\,}{\| \mathrm A \|_F}$$

and the minimum and maximum are $\pm \| \mathrm A \|_F$.

Comment: I am curious why you add bounties to questions that are already answered. You mentioned it was an experiment, so I am pinging you here not to ruin the experiment, but could you elaborate on it here?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking for alternative proofs of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. There are plenty of them even on this site. A quick google search reveals [an article](http://www.ajmaa.org/RGMIA/papers/v12e/Cauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf) that contains twelve proofs and I'd bet there is some literature out there that contains even more:

> Hui-Hua Wu and Shanhe Wu, *Various proofs of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality*.

Answer (score 1):

Those are correct, but you can also use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to deduce the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This optimization problem is equivalent to maximizing

$$\text{vec}(A)^T\text{vec}(X)$$

over the $(mn-1)$-sphere.  Thus the optimal point will just be the Frobenius normalization of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Make a change of variables to transform the problem into an unconstrained problem. 

For typing convenience, I'll use a colon (:) to denote the matrix inner product, e.g. 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Call the unconstrained variable $Y$, and find the differential of its length/norm.
$$\eqalign{
 \lambda^2 = \|Y\|_F^2 &=  Y:Y \cr
\lambda\,d\lambda &= Y:dY &\implies d\lambda &= \frac{Y:dY}{\lambda} \cr
}$$
Replace $X$ by $Y/\lambda\,\,$ in the function and differentiate
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= A:X = \frac{A:Y}{\lambda} \cr
d\phi
 &= \frac{\lambda A:dY-A:Y\,d\lambda}{\lambda^2} \cr
 &= \lambda^{-3}\Big(\lambda^2A - (A:Y)Y\Big):dY \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Y} &= \lambda^{-3}\Big((Y:Y)A - (A:Y)Y\Big)\cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve
$$\eqalign{
 (A:Y)Y &= (Y:Y)\,A \cr
 Y &= \pm\beta A \cr
 X &= Y/\|Y\|_F = \pm A/\|A\|_F \cr\cr
}$$
Admittedly, this is a bit clumsier than the other responses, but all of the good ideas were already taken.